# Web-audio-api audioPeak stops after 60 minutes

Tags: node.js

I have implemented web-audio-api and I am tracking the changes in volume across the file. The volume stops being tracked after 60 minutes. How can I ensure the audio is tracked for the full length of the file (or set the parameter to be something unreachable)?

audioPeak stops after 60 minutes:
[image: audioPeak stops after 60 minutes]

Answer (score 0):

It Seems it working perfectly. Please look at db and update

ALTER TABLE `tbl_filesforengineprocessing` CHANGE COLUMN `audio_peak` `audio_peak` LONGTEXT NULL AFTER `user_id`;